# Change terminal type for screen over a serial connection

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal, xterm

I am connecting to an embedded Linux board using `screen` over a serial link and trying to change the terminal type, as the default `vt100` is pretty restrictive in terms of colours and scrolling etc.

The `screen` manual suggests the configuration option `termcapinfo` but using that doesn't fix the issue.

On the host machine, `TERM` is set to `xterm-256color` and when I connect to the target, using the `termcapinfo` setting in my `.screenrc`, `TERM` is still set to `vt100`.

I am thinking maybe I should set something on the target machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the remote machine that sets `$TERM` to `vt100`, because it cannot know what terminal emulator your connecting with. `vt100` is a safe value as the majority of modern terminals and terminal emulators (including `screen`) are compatible.

To tell the applications over there what your terminal actually is, you have to set `$TERM` explicitely:

```
TERM=screen
```

You can do:

```
find $(infocmp -D) -printf '%f\n' | sort -u | grep screen
```

to see if there are more appropriate entries like `screen-256color`.

Comment: Thanks, I had a suspicion that I needed to add this to the target machine. Follow-up question: When  I ssh into a machine, `.bashrc` gets executed and sets `TERM=xterm-256color`. What would be the equivalent file or mechanism to a serial connection?

Comment: `.bashrc` should **not** set `TERM`, `TERM` is set by the terminal emulator itself, and passed by `ssh` to the shell started by `sshd` as part of the ssh protocol. In case of a serial console, the client cannot send a variable across the serial connection like that. It depends what application runs on that serial device. If it's a getty that starts `login` that starts bash (your login shell) as a login shell, then you could put the definition in your `~/.bash_profile`. Something like `[[ $(tty) = /dev/ttyS* ]] && TERM=screen-256color ]]` to set $TERM whenever the tty is a serial one.